# Sci fi book about space military supply ship someone is stealing

Tags: story-identification, books

The book is about a young officer straight out of academy. He gets chosen by the captain of a military supply ship to replace a dead cargo officer. One day he decided to open a crate to check that everything is fine with it and discovers that is filled with rocks. He orders a lockdown of the area and decides to check every crate. He finds many more crates filled with rocks, all ordered by the same officer. He lifts the lockdown, and goes to tell the captain. Before he goes to the captain, he decided to tell a friend about what he found just in case. When he and his friend meet, they both get attacked. They wake up in a shuttle stuck in warp.

It turns out the protagonist is heir from the richest family in the human empire, and godson to the emperor. The family has some kind of name with stone. They name their heirs with Latin number.

Comment: Can you go to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and try answering the questions there, editing the answers into your question? For example when did you read this? Where? Was it in English? Paperback? Hardback? EBook? So you remember how it ended?

Comment: Do the heirs have names like Primus, Secundus?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't mixing up two books? The stealing supplies stuff is in Walter Jon Williams' *The Sundering* (vol. 2 of *Dread Empire's Fall*), but the rest doesn't match.